# The App design is not visible in Android Studio, How to make it visible?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

[Design preview  Not visible in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8IBX.png)

The design preview for all other activities are visible, but for this specific activity(quiz_page.xml) the design preview is not visible.

I have tried all the things on the Internet including

1. Invalid caches
2. Force Refresh layout
3. Disabled and enabled Android support plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pressed this icon:

[image: errors icon]

you would get the desired reason why the design is not visible, please do that and update your question :)

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Android Studio, there's been a issue, **XML** will not be shown until you fix all the bugs available in your code.

**Solutions**

1. Downgrade your Android Studio to **BumbleBee**. By this, xml will be shown if error still exists in code.
2. Fix issues illustrated by android studio. You can find issues by clicking red error icon on top-right side of xml page.